# Unable to Return JSON Object from jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to correctly return (or maybe "capture" is a better term) a JSON object from within a function that runs on page load.  I'd like to capture that object so that I can subsequently POST it to another page by user action.

I'm running this on Windows 10, Firefox latest.

```
var configJson;
$(document).ready(function () { // Wait till page is loaded
    configJson = getConfig();
    console.log("Outside: " + JSON.stringify(configJson)); // DEBUG
});

function getConfig() {
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/config/", function () {
        //console.log("Success."); // DEBUG
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log("Inside: " + JSON.stringify(data)); // DEBUG
            return data;
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("Fail."); // DEBUG
            return JSON.parse("{}");
        })
}
```

From the console, "Outside" is what is returned, "Inside" is what's seen in the function:

```
Inside: {"name":"fred"}
Outside: undefined
```

Comment: Yes, it's because your ajax call $.getJSON is async. So the console.log("Outside") is executed before the end of the $.getJSON call.
You can use a callback in the function getConfig() and call a console log with the  result of the callback.
You can take a look in the doc for the deffered object and see some examples. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return data from an asynchronous function, so you will need to use a callback. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getConfig(function(configJson) {
        console.log("Outside: " + JSON.stringify(configJson));
        // do something with configJson here.
    });
});

function getConfig(callback) {
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/config/")
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log("Inside: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            callback(data);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("Failed!");
            callback({});
        });
}
```

If you need a global variable containing the config, you could do something like this:

```
var globalConfig = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    getConfig(function(configJson) {
        globalConfig = configJson;
    });
});
// ...
```

Comment: And I even ready that about async and completely spaced it!  Thank you for your assistance.